# RecyclerView adapter showing wrong images

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml, android-recyclerview

I have a RecyclerView adapter that looks like this:

```
public class RecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private static Context context;
    private List<Message> mDataset;

    public RecyclerAdapter(Context context, List<Message> myDataset) {
        this.context = context;
        this.mDataset = myDataset;
    }

    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnCreateContextMenuListener, View.OnClickListener {
        public TextView title;
        public LinearLayout placeholder;

        public ViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            view.setOnCreateContextMenuListener(this);

            title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title);
            placeholder = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.placeholder);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.message_layout, parent, false);
        ViewHolder vh = new ViewHolder((LinearLayout) view);

        return vh;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Message item = mDataset.get(position);

        holder.title.setText(item.getTitle());

        int numImages = item.getImages().size();

        if (numImages > 0) {
            View test = LayoutInflater.from(holder.placeholder.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.images, holder.placeholder, false);
            ImageView image = (ImageView) test.findViewById(R.id.image);
            Glide.with(context)
                .load("http://www.website.com/test.png")
                .fitCenter()
                .into(image);
            holder.placeholder.addView(test);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mDataset.size();
    }

}
```

However, some of the items in the RecyclerView are showing images when they shouldn't be. How can I stop this from happening?

I do the check `if (numImages > 0) {` in `onBindViewHolder()`, but that's still not stopping it from showing images for items that shouldn't have images.

Comment: If you got an answer, please approve it

Answer (score 31):

You should set `imageView.setImageDrawable (null)`
In `onBindViewHolder()` before setting the image using glide.

Setting image drawable to null fix the issue.

Hope it helps!

Comment: works, but it slow down the scrolling a bit as it loads image again.

Comment: Thanks, worked for me..and fast scrolling has slower little bit. expected result is to not misplaced images..so upvoted..

Comment: I have a small doubt, let's assume when screen first-time loads it's having an image then on some updates accordingly, this imageview changes so at which moment I should set it to null? Please clarify my doubt. Thanks in advance. :)

Answer (score 20):

The problem is in onBindViewHolder, here:

```
    if (numImages > 0) {
        View test = LayoutInflater.from(holder.placeholder.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.images, holder.placeholder, false);
        ImageView image = (ImageView) test.findViewById(R.id.image);
        Glide.with(context)
            .load("http://www.website.com/test.png")
            .fitCenter()
            .into(image);
        holder.placeholder.addView(test);
    }
```

If numImages is equal to 0, you're simply allowing the previously started load into the view you're reusing to continue. When it finishes, it will still load the old image into your view. To prevent this, tell Glide to cancel the previous load by calling clear:

```
   if (numImages > 0) {
        View test = LayoutInflater.from(holder.placeholder.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.images, holder.placeholder, false);
        ImageView image = (ImageView) test.findViewById(R.id.image);
        Glide.with(context)
            .load("http://www.website.com/test.png")
            .fitCenter()
            .into(image);
        holder.placeholder.addView(test);
    } else {
        Glide.clear(image);
    }
```

When you call `into()`, Glide handles canceling the old load for you. If you're not going to call `into()`, you must call `clear()` yourself.

Every call to onBindViewHolder must include either a `load()` call or a `clear()` call.

Comment: using `clear()` is the best way to handle pending requests caused by recycling

Comment: you add a main point to some topic around here. there are bunch of topics around the recyclerview messed up items while scrolling. i think this is the solution for that situation in some cases. anyway, thank you very much.

Comment: Use "Glide.with(viewholder.itemView.getContext()).clear(viewHolder.getImageView());" in glide 4.9

Answer (score 11):

I also had issues with RecyclerView showing wrong images. This happens because RecyclerView is not inflating view for every new list item: instead list items are being recycled.

By recycling views we can ruffly understand **cloning** views. A cloned view might have an image set from the previous interaction.

This is especially fair if your are using Picasso, Glide, or some other lib for async loading. These libs hold reference to an ImageView, and set an image on that refference when image is loaded.

By the time the image gets loaded, the item view might have gotten  cloned, and the image is going to be set to the **wrong clone**.

To make a long story short, I solved this problem by restricting RecyclerView from cloning my item views:

`setIsRecyclable(false)`in ViewHolder constructor.

Now   RecyclerView is working a bit slower, but at least the images are set right.

Or else cansel loading image in `onViewRecycled(ViewHolder holde)`

Comment: According to the android SDK documentation :

call to setIsRecyclabe(false) should always be matched with a later call to
setIsRecyclable(true)). Pairs of calls may be nested, as the state is internally reference-counted.

[RecyclerView#setIsRecycable](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.ViewHolder.html#setIsRecyclable(boolean))

Your solution is unfortunately not recommended.

Comment: This is not recommended especially for very large and heavy datasets. Answer by Prashant Solanki is the better option.

Comment: There is not much point of using a recyclerview if you set the recyclable property false.

Answer (score 5):

The issue here is that, as you are working with views that are going to be recycled, you'll need to handle all the possible scenarios at the time your binding your view.

For example, if you're adding the ImageView to the LinearLayout on position 0 of the data source, then, if position 4 doesn't met the condition, its view will most likely have the ImageView added when binding position 0.

You can add the content of R.layout.images content inside your

**R.layout.message_layout** layout's **R.id.placeholder** and showing/hiding the placeholder depending on the case.

So, your onBindViewHolder method would be something like:

```
@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Message item = mDataset.get(position);

        holder.title.setText(item.getTitle());

        int numImages = item.getImages().size();

        if (numImages > 0) {
            holder.placeholder.setVisivility(View.VISIBLE);
            ImageView image = (ImageView)holder.placeholder.findViewById(R.id.image);
            Glide.with(context)
                .load("http://www.website.com/test.png")
                .fitCenter()
                .into(image);
        }else{
           holder.placeholder.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
    }
```

Comment: If I just make `placeholder` invisible, doesn't that mean it's still loading the image, but hiding it?

Comment: @user5578746 yes, i think that could happen. But i assume that if you don't have images to show, you don't want to display the images container whatsoever

Comment: Yes, but for performance, I'd also rather not load the image unecessarily. You also missed out the line where I inflate another layout, which means it's inflating the layout as well as loading the image, and then hiding it.

Comment: @user5578746 in the example above, the image is not loaded unless you have one to show. As the views are recycled, you need a way to prevent the user from seeing images loaded for a another iteration. Please explain, why do you see a performance issue?

Comment: `setVisibility()` hides the image. But does that mean the image is still being loaded?

Comment: It's now showing multiple images per item, where it should only be showing one.

Comment: Can you provide more information regarding your implementation? for instance, the layouts you're using? It is very hard to help you with only one piece of code

Answer (score 4):

Sometimes when using RecyclerView, a View may be re-used and retain the size from a previous position that will be changed for the current position. To handle those cases, you can create a new [ViewTarget and pass in true for waitForLayout]:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(VH holder, int position) {
  Glide.with(fragment)
    .load(urls.get(position))
    .into(new DrawableImageViewTarget(holder.imageView,/*waitForLayout=*/ true));
```

https://bumptech.github.io/glide/doc/targets.html

Comment: this is deprecated in glide 4+

Answer (score 3):

I also had the same problem and ended with below solution and it working fine for me..

Have your hands on this solution might be work for you too (Put below code in your adapter class)-

**If you are using Kotlin -**

```
override fun getItemId(position: Int): Long {
        return position.toLong()
    }

    override fun getItemViewType(position: Int): Int {
        return position
    }
```

**If you are using JAVA -**

```
 @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

@Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return position;
    }
```

Comment: With this solution, the adapter thinks that every item is a different type of view, losing the reuse benefit of `RecyclerView`. This may decrease performance significantly.

Comment: perfect solution for me, surprisingly simple - thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This works for me in onBindViewHolder!

```
if(!m.getPicture().isEmpty())
{
    holder.setIsRecyclable(false);
    Picasso.with(holder.profile_pic.getContext()).load(m.getPicture()).placeholder(R.mipmap.ic_launcher_round).into(holder.profile_pic);
    Animation fadeOut = new AlphaAnimation(0, 1);
    fadeOut.setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator());
    fadeOut.setDuration(1000);
    holder.profile_pic.startAnimation(fadeOut);
}
else
{
    holder.setIsRecyclable(true);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I was having same issue I solved by writing `holder.setIsRecyclable(false)`.
Worked for me.

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecylerViewHolder holder, int position) {
    NewsFeed currentFeed = newsFeeds.get(position);
    holder.textView.setText(currentFeed.getNewsTitle());
    holder.sectionView.setText(currentFeed.getNewsSection());
    if(currentFeed.getImageId() == "NOIMG") {
        holder.setIsRecyclable(false);
        Log.v("ImageLoad","Image not loaded");
    } else {
        Picasso.get().load(currentFeed.getImageId()).into(holder.imageView);
        Log.v("ImageLoad","Image id "+ currentFeed.getImageId());
    }
    holder.dateView.setText(getModifiedDate(currentFeed.getDate()));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
   override fun getItemId(position: Int): Long {
        return position.toLong()
    }

    override fun getItemViewType(position: Int): Int {
        return position
    }
```

This Works for Me

Answer (score 0):

I Had the same issue and i fixed it like this:

**GOAL : onViewAttachedToWindow**

```
@Override
public void onViewAttachedToWindow(Holder holder) {
    super.onViewAttachedToWindow(holder);
    StructAllItems sfi = mArrayList.get(position);   
    if (!sfi.getPicHayatParking().isEmpty()) {
        holder.viewFliperMelk.addSlider(new TextSliderView(mContext.getApplicationContext()).image(T.GET_MELK_IMAGE + '/' + sfi.getPicHayatParking() + ".jpg").setScaleType(BaseSliderView.ScaleType.CenterCrop));
    }
    if (!sfi.getPicSleepRoom().isEmpty()) {
        holder.viewFliperMelk.addSlider(new TextSliderView(mContext.getApplicationContext()).image(T.GET_MELK_IMAGE + '/' + sfi.getPicSleepRoom() + ".jpg").setScaleType(BaseSliderView.ScaleType.CenterCrop));
    }
    if (!sfi.getPicSalonPazirayi().isEmpty()) {
        holder.viewFliperMelk.addSlider(new TextSliderView(mContext.getApplicationContext()).image(T.GET_MELK_IMAGE + '/' + sfi.getPicSalonPazirayi() + ".jpg").setScaleType(BaseSliderView.ScaleType.CenterCrop));
    }
    if (!sfi.getPicNamayeStruct().isEmpty()) {
        holder.viewFliperMelk.addSlider(new TextSliderView(mContext.getApplicationContext()).image(T.GET_MELK_IMAGE + '/' + sfi.getPicNamayeStruct() + ".jpg").setScaleType(BaseSliderView.ScaleType.CenterCrop));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue when getting pictures from the photo gallery and putting them in a recyclerview with GridLayoutManager(never had the issue with Glide). So in the adapter onBindViewHolder use a HashMap or SparseIntArray to put the current hashcode(this is the common thing that the recycled views have in common) and adapter position inside it.  Then call your background task and then once it's done and before you set the image, check to see if the hashcode key - which will always have the current adapter position as the value - still has the same value (adapter position) as when you first called the background task.

```
(Global variable)
   private SparseIntArray hashMap = new SparseIntArray();

onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position){

   holder.imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.grey_square);
   hashMap.put(holder.hashCode(), position);
   yourBackgroundTask(ViewHolder holder, int position);
}

yourBackGroundTask(ViewHolder holder, int holderPosition){

   do some stuff in the background.....
      *if you want to stop to image from downloading / or in my case 
       fetching the image from MediaStore then do - 
         if(hashMap.get(holder.hashCode())!=(holderPos)){
                 return null;
             } 
         - in the background task, before the call to get the 
           image

   onPostExecute{
      if(hashMap.get(holder.hashCode())==(holderPosition)){
         holder.imageView.setImageBitmap(result);
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So i am just providing an extension to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34236538/7873768) answer since there is not much space to leave it as comment.

After trying out like mentioned in one of above solutions i found out that, the real issue can still be addressed even if you are using a static resource(is not being downloaded and is available locally)

So basically on onBindViewHolder event i just converted the resource to drawable and added it like below :

```
imageView.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(context,R.drawable.album_art_unknown));
```

this way you wont have an empty space on the view while glide/async downloader is loading the actual image from network.

plus looking at that being reloaded every time i also added below code while calling the recycler adapter class;

```
recyclerView.setItemViewCacheSize(10);
recyclerView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
```

so by using above way you wont need to set setIsRecyclable(false) which is degrading if you have larger datasets.

By doing this i you will have a flicker free loading of recyclerview of course except for the initial loads.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to say that if you send the `ImageView` and any load-async command (for instance loading from `S3`), the recycler view does get confused.

I did set the bitmap null in the `onViewRecycled` and tested with attach and detach views etc. the issue never went away.

The issue is that if a holderView gets used for `image-1`, `image-10` and stops at the scroll with `image-19`, what the user sees is `image-1`, then `image-10` and then `image-19`.

One method that worked for me is to keep a hash_map that helps know what is the latest image that needs to be displayed on that `ImageView`.

Remember, the holder is recycled, so the hash for that view is persistent.

1- Create this map for storing what image should be displayed,

```
public static HashMap<Integer, String> VIEW_SYNCHER = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
```

2- In your Adapter, onBindViewHolder,

```
String thumbnailCacheKey = "img-url";
        GLOBALS.VIEW_SYNCHER.put(holder.thumbnailImage.hashCode(), thumbnailCacheKey);
```

3- Then you have some async call to make the network call and load the image in the view right ?
In that code after loading the image from S3, you test to make sure what goes into the View,

```
// The ImageView in the network data loader, get its hash.
  int viewCode = iim.imView[0].hashCode();

 if (GLOBALS.VIEW_SYNCHER.containsKey(viewCode))
                if (GLOBALS.VIEW_SYNCHER.get(viewCode).equals(bitmapKey))
                 iim.imView[0].setImageBitmap(GLOBALS.BITMAP_CACHE.get(bitmapKey).bitmapData);
```

So essentially, you make sure what is the last image key that should go into a view, then when you download the image you check to make sure that's the last image URL that goes in that view.

This solution worked for me.